# Proxy configured through .pac file behind enterprise VPN doesn't apply to CURL (terminal) commands

Tags: terminal, network, command-line, vpn, proxy

I can make a request to `https://www.google.com` in the browser behind VPN but when I curl that, it doesn't work.

But if I disable VPN and do a `curl https://www.google.com` it will send a response.

With VPN, the same curl request just hangs.

To me, it seems like the proxy setting set up in the adapter by the PAC file (under `Automatic Proxy Configuration`) isn't applied to the terminal/curl.

Anyone experience this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proxies are not automatically used system-wide. Applications must actively use them. The proxy configuration is applied to your browser, but `curl` is not affected.

To use `curl` with a proxy, you have to use the `-x` option to provide the proxy address.

Answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7559103) may also be of interest to you.

Comment: oh i see, thanks. Do you have any idea how I can extract the proxy information from a .PAC file?

Comment: @TolgaE The .pac file defines a JavaScript function that returns the proxy. Just peek into it to find out which. You may want to take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config for details.

Comment: great stuff, thanks @not2savvy I just got the proxy working!